# Replacing &#038; in JS code on pages

Tags: javascript, wp-autop, customization

I am needing to remove the `&#038;` that seems to be replacing my `&` on my page code.

My original code looked like this:

```
$.get("../form/master.php?called=CAP&captcha="+$("#captcha_txt").val(), {}, function(response){
```

and now, looking at the source code to the page that loads that within wordpress:

```
$.get("../form/master.php?called=CAP&#038;captcha="+$("#captcha_txt").val(), {}, function(response){
```

What can i do in order for it not to replace my `&` within my JS code?

Comment: How do you add this code to your posts?

Comment: Just placing it inside <script></script>

Comment: Do your put this code in a template, or do you use `wp_enqueue_script()`?

Comment: Inside the WP editor (html). I have the plugin **Toggle wpautop**

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing this and it works:

```
var data = {
    called: 'CAP',
    captcha: $("#captcha_txt").val()
};

$.get("../form/master.php",data,function(response){
....
});
```